Product of Two Uniformly Continuous Function
Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be an uniformly continous function such that $|x| f(x)$ is also an uniformly continous function. Prove that for every $g: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ uniformly continous function, $f.g(x)$ is also an uniformly continous function.
My attempt:
My first plan was to bound it and I've shown that
$$f.g(x) \le a |x|f(x) + bf(x)$$
for some constant $a, b$. But I don't know what to do next.
Edit:
By triangle Inequality
\begin{align*}
|fg(x) - fg(y)| & \le |f(x)| |g(x) - g(y)| + |g(y)| |f(x) - f(y)|
\end{align*}
It looks like $f$ is bounded because $|x|f(x)$, but I still don't know how to handle the $g(y)$. I try limiting $g(y)$ using $|g(x) - g(y)| < 1$
\begin{align*}
|f(x)| |g(x) - g(y)| + |g(y)| |f(x) - f(y)| &\le |f(x)| |g(x) - g(y)| + (|g(x)| + 1) |f(x) - f(y)| \\
&\le \varepsilon_0 (|f(x)| + |g(x)| + 1)
\end{align*}

You'll want to do this with $\epsilon$s and $\delta$s. Write out the hypotheses you know (using different functions $\delta_\epsilon$ of $\epsilon$) and the claim you want to show. Use the triangle inequality on the latter, see how it relates to the former.

Hint: $f$ is bounded. (Because $|xf(x)|\le A|x|+B$)

@geetha290krm but wouldn't that just implies $|f(x)| \le A + \frac{B}{|x|}$ for $|x| > 0$. How to show it bounded from there cause when $|x| < 1$ the second term exploded

Any continuous function is bounded on $[-1,1]$.
